# Stagemanager/Split View - How to get window resize event when view controller is presented on different window and in minimised mode

Tags: ios, swift

I have an application where we have presented a view controller on a separate window and window is in minimised mode similar to PIP(Not using any pip APIs here. Its customised view). When on stage manager/split view, I want to resize the window based on app's primary window dynamically.

I see that viewWillTransition gets called only for the view controllers inside app's primary window which is in full screen.

Do we have universal window size did change events in iOS similar to window resize events on MacOS?

One solution would be to have BaseVC to implement  viewWillTransition and throw notification to be observed by other VCs inside different windows. All the view controllers inside app's primary window should inherit from base vc.

Please suggest any alternative solutions.

Answer (score 0):

`UiWindowSceneDelagate` has `windowScene(_:didUpdate:interfaceOrientation:traitCollection:)` which notifies you when the size, orientation, or traits of a scene change.

Implement that method and broadcast the event using `NotificationCenter`.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try this solution